# iOS/Xcode - Multiple segue identifiers resetting data parsing

Tags: ios, tableview, segue

So I got a ViewController with 4 seperate buttons. When clicking on button1 TableViewController1 pops over the ViewController with a list of items. When selecting an item the TableViewController1 drops down and button1 now has the text that was selected in the table. This is all good. But when I do the exact same thing for button2 with TableViewController2 the data from button1 is reseted.

I use segues with identifiers, some of the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEducation"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewEducation indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.educationText = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

So at the moment I got multiple segue identifiers for each button and multiple .h and .m files for the tableviews. Am I using a completely wrong technique to get this to work? I hope im clear enough, otherwise I can upload images.

Edit: I just noticed, I also have a slider on my ViewController. When clicking on a button and selecting a row in the TableView the slider gets reseted to the original position. Same problem as above kind of.

Comment: are your two separate TableViewController objects using the same object/class for their data source?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: does one class or object have your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" methods, or does each TableViewController object have their own?

Comment: Each TableViewController has its own. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing without knowing more about how you're going back and forth between your controllers. When do you see that the data from button 1 is reset -- do you come back to that first controller to see that, or can you always see those 4 buttons?

Comment: Nope. This is not wrong.

Comment: I come back to the first controller. Controller 1 displays 4 buttons, when clicked a new controller pops up with variables, when clicking on a variable you get back to controller 1 displaying the value but resetting this as soon as the process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you're pushing to a new instance of your View Controller every time you push from either tableViewController.

Imagine that you click on one button on ViewController0, this creates an instance of tableViewController1. When you click a row, you're just using a performSegue to create a NEW instance of ViewController0, and this has its own ViewDidLoad - resetting the buttons.

(You're saying that the view "drops down", so it's modal?)
Don't use `performSegue` from the tableViewController back to the viewController, try using `[self dismissModalViewController: withCompletion:]`(or something similar, can't remember), then your tableViewController should remove itself and reveal the original ViewController.

Now, you don't have a way to change the name of the button though, but that can be done by accessing the `sender` from the tableView, which will give you the original View Controller, and not a new instance of it.

One way of getting the sender is to use `[performSegue...` from ViewController0, and in it's own `prepareForSegue`, you could do something like

```
//In the first ViewController, not in the TableViewControllers
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if(sender == button1)
    {
        UITableViewController1 *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        [dest setSender: self];
    }
}
```

And in TableViewController1 you'd create a variable `ViewController *home;`, and a method `-(void)setSender:(ViewController*)sender;`, so that in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you could now say `[[(ViewController0*)home button1]setTitle:@..];`, and then `[dismissModalViewController..]`

There are other ways to do it as well, depending on how you are pushing from your viewController to the tableViewController. And I'm sure there are easier ways to access the sender than this, but it works and is useful if you're already sending other data.

Comment: Wow what a nice explanation. It seems very logical if I read this, im gonna try out the code but I have no idea how to implement it just yet.

Comment: Im not using performSegue by the way, im animating between the views through the storyboard.

Comment: @Torylon So, in storyboard, did you make a segue (one of these lines between views) from viewController to tableViewController, AND another one from tableViewController to viewController? Cause that's wrong. Remove the segue(line) starting from tableViewController, and inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath try either [self dismissModalViewController...] OR [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to see if it's responding correctly

Comment: Yea I did, I just removed the segue from tableView to ViewController. I did not use didSelectRowAtIndexPath so where do I implement this?

Comment: - (void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //[self dismissModalViewController...]
   // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
Tried various ways and it doesnt seem to dismiss anything.

Comment: tracing :   NSLog(@"Cell check %@", [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); returns the correct value so I would think the tableViewController isnt dismissing because I use storyboard segue's to make it pop up?

Comment: Ok I got it to dismiss but I cant for the life of me figure out how to implement your code.

Comment: @Torylon How did you end up dismissing it? What method? So now it's dismissing when you click on a row? How are you getting from ViewController to TableViewController? Simply by the storyboard-segue? In that case, if you implement `-(void)prepareForSegue...` as in my answer, it should be called, even though you've just set it to push through Storyboard. Try implementing the method in ViewController, and put `NSLog(@"Hello");` inside it, and see if it's printing out when you click any button.